# In this movie a woman fears that something terrible has happened in the past but it turns out to be a premonition

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie I saw on a few years ago but I cannot remember the title. A couple (the woman is pregnant) move to a house in wine country. She soon starts to get a feeling that something very bad has happened there. Certain places nearby (a well is one of them) call up a lot of fear in her. But as it happens these are not things that have happened but things that are going to happen in the movie. In flashbacks you see that the woman had an auto accident (not her fault) in which another woman lost her child. What is going to happen is that this other woman reenters her life seeking revenge.

Answer (score 22):

This is ***[Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_(film))***.

> *Visions* is a 2015 American supernatural horror film directed by Kevin Greutert. It is written by Lucas Susan. Jason Blum serves as a producer through his production company Blumhouse Productions. The film stars Isla Fisher, Anson Mount, Gillian Jacobs, Jim Parsons, Joanna Cassidy, and Eva Longoria. It was released by Universal Pictures through video on demand on January 19, 2016, prior to being released through home media formats on February 2, 2016.

At the start of the film, the main character, Eveleigh, is receiving medical treatment in hospital, after having been in an auto accident where another woman lost her infant child.

A year later, Eveleigh is pregnant, and she and her husband have recently moved from Los Angeles to a house in the countryside, where they plan to reopen an old vineyard. Before long, Eveleigh begins seeing and hearing strange things, like a body floating in a nearby pond, a bloody handprint on a wall, and a shadowy figure wearing a hood. Her husband can't see any of this, and thinks the visions are just symptoms of PTSD from the auto accident, combined with hormones caused by her pregnancy.

Eveleigh becomes convinced that the house must be haunted, and this belief is reinforced when an older woman with some apparent psychic ability tells her that something terrible happened on the property, which stained the land, and that certain acts of psychic violence can echo throughout time, like ripples across a pond.

What Eveleigh comes to realise by the climax of the film is that the aforementioned ripples go *both* ways through time, and that the things she was seeing and hearing were visions of events which lay in her future rather than the past.

Comment: Logic has Dictated the Answer! Thanks, that's exactly what it is and thanks again.

Comment: @user47843 - Please don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: As a sidenote for any _Star Trek_ fans reading this, this film features the actor John de Lancie -- aka Q -- in a supporting role.